# Cake: How to get result from MSpec

Tags: continuous-integration, cakebuild

i tried to write a cake script for my ci. I'm new to cake.
As part of this script I wanted to execute MSpec tests.

```
Task("Run-Tests")
.IsDependentOn("Build")
.Does(() => {
    var configurationIntoTests = configuration + "/*.Tests.dll";

    MSpec("../src/ERP.BusniessLogic.Tests/bin" + configurationIntoTests);
    MSpec("../src/ERP.DapperDataAccess.Tests/bin" + configurationIntoTests);
    MSpec("../src/ERP.DomainModel.Tests/bin" + configurationIntoTests);
    MSpec("../src/ERP.Shared.Tests/bin" + configurationIntoTests);
    MSpec("../src/ERP.Web.Tests/bin" + configurationIntoTests);
});
```

I assumed that it would give a console output as MSBuild does, since it has no return value. [See API](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSpec/MSpecAliases/24D18B6E)

As you may expect there is no console output, which means I don't know what the result of the tests is.

How can i get this result to report it to my ci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [MSpec(string, MSpecSettings)](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSpec/MSpecAliases/44E938DD) overload will let you set what kind of report, it's name and where to put it using the [MSpecSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSpec/MSpecSettings/) class.

```
 MSpec("../src/Progresso.ERP.BusniessLogic.Tests/bin/" + configurationIntoTests,
 new MSpecSettings {
    ReportName = "Progresso.ERP.BusniessLogic.Tests",
    HtmlReport = true,
    OutputDirectory = "./build"
});
```

**Update**

Studying your example code I notice a `/` is missing before configuration

```
var configurationIntoTests = configuration + "/*.Tests.dll";
```

should be

```
var configurationIntoTests = "/" + configuration + "/*.Tests.dll";
```

Otherwise i.e. `bin/Debug/` becomes `binDebug` and the test globber will not find any assemblies and MSPec won't even be executed.